# Comparing 2 datasets

Tags: loops, comparison, matching

I'm been looking for the best way to create a look up table which holds every record ID for database 1 alongside every record ID from data base. So if one database had 10 records no the second had 5 the look up table would have 50 row, 10x5 and my look up table looks like this

1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 6
3 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relational database, like SQL, you can reference a primary key from another table. This would be called a foreign key.

If you have a one to many relationship, meaning a record from table A could be assigned to multiple records in table B, but table B can only relate to one record in table A; then you can add table A's primary key as a foreign key in table B. In this scenario you do not have to create a separate table that maintains the relationships.

If you have a many to many between the two tables, meaning that records from table A can relate to multiple records in table B and vice versa, then you do require a third table with two columns containing the primary keys of each table.

Let the database engine do the work for you. You can then write a basic join query to lookup the related records.